# ASP.Net Ajax Control Toolkit - Password Strength always display message after input

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have used the above control on a register form. An example of the functionality can be seen here:

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/passwordstrength/passwordstrength.aspx

The client has requested that the password Text Indicator (displayed to the right of the control) doesn't dissapear when the password control looses focus. I can see his point on this.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: This is strictly my opinion, but ditch ASP.NET AJAX and just use jQuery. ASP.NET Ajax is old and so.... bad....

Comment: I use both, ASP.Net Ajax has its uses as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function ValidatorValidate(val) onblur:

- Takes a client-validator as input. Makes the validator check its input and update its display.

MSDN Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx